# About ubuntu16.04 partition operation

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

I want to install a Windows dual system with a free partition on a disk that already has ubuntu16.04 installed. How to merge those two free partitions?

I have tried to operate by moving the partition, but when moving the `/home` partition, the prompt can not be operated, there is a process. Re-operation after releasing the memory or prompting the same information.

[image]

Comment: if you want to install Windows, their is only 3 steps : 1-Save all your files into an external drive 2-Install Windows, you can't avoid Windows to formate the whole disk of your computer, that's why you must save your data before Windows installation 3-Reinstall Ubuntu after Windows installation, and then you can transfer your previous data

Comment: You can't move partitions that are mounted .. that is all partitions that shows a lock-key. You will have to boot on a Live media and run gparted from there.